# Is there a way to pass Environment variables through a Monit config

Tags: monit

I have a script that needs to be kept alive by Monit.  How can I pass my environment variables to this script?  Something like:

```
check host steve with address localhost
        group nn
        ENV = "DBHOST=localhost" #this doesn't work...
        start program = "/home/steve.sh start"
        start program = "/home/steve.sh restart"
        if failed port 80 protocol http for 2 cycles then restart
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to pass `ENV` to the script with monit.

The easiest way to get this done might be using parameters:

Add a *bridge script* `/home/monit_steve.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
export DBHOST="$1"
/home/steve.sh "$2"
exit $?
```

Then update your `monitrc` to match (you currently have 2x `start program`...):

```
check host steve with address localhost
  group nn
  start program = "/home/monit_steve.sh localhost start"
  restart program = "/home/monit_steve.sh localhost restart"
  if failed port 80 protocol http for 2 cycles then restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you can use $HOST for this purpose but looks like there are not others available.